# CSS transform translate not updating height of container

Tags: html, css, animation

I have the following html markup

```
<div class="wrapper" style="position: relative;" >
 <img src="..." style="width:100%; height:auto">
<div class="description" style="position:absolute;left:0;bottom:0;width:100%">
figure caption
</div>
</div>
```

And i handle the click on the image to move the caption out of the image to the bottom of it.
The css markup looks like

```
.wrapper.full .description{
transform: translate(0,100%);
}
.description{ transition: all .4s ease-in-out;}
```

But the problem is that the height of the wrapper is not changing as i want. I would like the height to be `h = image_heigth + caption_height`
Because there is more content below and i want to push it down and allocate space for the description. Actually the descriptions appears outside the wrapper as it does not change size and overlaps with the content below it. Any help?
JS code

```
$('.wrapper img').click(function(){
var wrapper= $(this).parents('.wrapper');
wrapper.addClass('full');

)};
```

Comment: there is no `.full` and `.description` in the HTML snippet you provided

Comment: @Lal can you post fiddle ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code below: 
HTML

```
<div class="wrapper" style="position: relative;" >
 <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/" style="width:100%; height:auto">
<div class="caption" style="position:absolute;left:0;bottom:0;width:100%">
figure caption
</div>
</div>

<!--Design 2-->
<div class="wrapper sample_2" style="position: relative;" >
 <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/" style="width:100%; height:auto">
<div class="caption" style="position:absolute;left:0;bottom:0;width:100%">
figure caption
</div>
</div>
```

Css

```
.wrapper{
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    padding:10px;
    background:red;
    overflow:hidden;
    transition:all .5s;
}
.wrapper:hover{
    height:400px;
}
.wrapper .caption{
    width:100%;
    height:200px;
    top:220px;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    position:absolute;
    background:green;
    padding:10px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}

/*Design 2*/
.wrapper.sample_2:hover{
    height:200px;
}
.wrapper.sample_2 .caption{
    transition:all .5s;
}
.wrapper.sample_2:hover .caption{
    top:0;
}
```

See this live demo on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sLye6bcy/)

See the second demo on [jsfiddle-2](http://jsfiddle.net/sLye6bcy/1/)